# liquibase roll back with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I have a spring boot app(v2.3.3) which contains Liquidbase tool to create my table and initialise it.
When I start spring boos it is working fine, the tables are created and data inserted by using sql scripts  and the Liquidbase configs are shown below:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/db.master.xml
```

src/main/resources/db: db.master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
    <includeAll path="scripts/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>`enter code here`

</databaseChangeLog>
```

src/main/resources/db/script/

- 001.createTableAudit.sql
- 002.insertDataTableAudit.sql

Let say I want to rollback 002.insertDataTableAudit.sql, is it possible rollback the insertDataTableAudit
when starting my Spring Boot App?

I know it can be done by maven : `mvn liquibase:rollback` but is it possible to acheive the same thing with Spring Boot?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such functionality in spring boot out of the box.
However you can create that functionality easily:

```
final Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("changelogpath", new CompositeResourceAccessor(new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), database);
liquibase.rollback("TAG", (String) null);
```